# pwauth kerberos authentication specifying default and secondary servers

Tags: authentication, apache-2.4, kerberos, pam

I am currently using Kerberos authentication for Basic Authentication on Apache using pwauth and mod_auth_external. I would like to add multiple servers to authenticate from, however they would have to specify the other servers similar to logging onto a domained windows computer. If it is the default server, then they would not have to specify a domain name. How would I go about accomplishing this? Thanks!

Example:

- default-server.local has user1.
- other-server.local has user2.
- user1 can login to Basic Auth in apache by simply tying in user1/pass. However, for user2, they would have to type other-server.local\user2 which would allow authentication.

How would this also work for typing into `require user` for .htaccess?